# Looping through array of object and filter based on property

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am currently passing an array of objects from one VC to another. This is fine, as I am able to pass the data over, however in *ViewDidLoad()* when I loop through the array and append to a new array the new array is always blank.

I've gone through several answers on stackoverflow, but all of them are simply suggesting what I have tried and should work e.g. for loop or using filter. I've replicated in PLaygrounds and it seems to work fine there, so not really sure what is happening

## A brief breakdown:

1. Configured FirebaseDB in initial viewcontroller, using data model append to first array
2. Data passed over using *prepare for segue*
3. In *ViewDidLoad()* loop through array of objects and use filter to append to new array if specific property matches (I tried using a for loop and an if statement, similar effect)

---

Data Model:

```swift
 struct resortData {

    var resort: String = ""
    var passengerName: String = ""
    var hotel: String = ""
    var rmNumber: Int = 0
  }
```

ResortVC (initial VC):

```swift
class ResortViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var resortArray: [resortData] = [resortData]()
    var currentResort: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        SVProgressHUD.show()

        title = "Resort"

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(loggedOut))

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        configureDB()

    }


    @objc func loggedOut() {

        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

        } catch {
            print("Error signing out")
        }
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return resortArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.resortLabel.text = resortArray[indexPath.row].resort
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        cell.resortCountryLocation.text = "Spain"
        cell.resortImg.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        cell.resortImg.image = UIImage(named: resortArray[indexPath.row].resort + ".png")
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            cell.alpha = 1
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        currentResort = resortArray[indexPath.row].resort

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToPassengerDetail", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToPassengerDetail" {

                    let detailVC = segue.destination as! ResortDetailTableViewController
                    detailVC.passengers = resortArray
                    detailVC.selectedResort = currentResort    
        }
    }


    func configureDB() {

        let tableData = Database.database().reference().child("masterSheet")

        tableData.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! NSArray
            let resort = snapshotValue[0] as! String
            let name = snapshotValue[1] as! String
            let hotel = snapshotValue[5] as! String
            let roomNumber = snapshotValue[6] as! Int

            var resortDB = resortData()
            resortDB.resort = resort
            resortDB.passengerName = name
            resortDB.hotel = hotel
            resortDB.rmNumber = roomNumber

            self.resortArray.append(resortDB)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

        }
    }


}
```

DetailVC:

```swift
    class ResortDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

        var passengers = [resortData]()
        var selectedResort: String?
        var filteredPassengerArray = [resortData]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            title = "Passenger Info "
            print(selectedResort ?? "No data passed over")

            filteredPassengerArray = passengers.filter { $0.hotel == selectedResort }
            print(filteredPassengerArray)
        }
```

**filteredPassengerArray** should only contain objects with specific property of **passengers.hotel**

Comment: But passengers is empty. So there is nothing to filter.

Comment: Are you sure there is something in `passengers` _before_ the filter? Do a `print(passengers.count)` and  see what the value is.

Comment: You say "data passed over in `prepare(for:sender:)`. Passed over how? Into what variable? Show that code, plus the definition of your `resortData` structur , and add a print statement to that function that shows the value you are passing in. Also log the value of `selectedResort`. If you don't set that, your filter will delete every record that has a non-nil hotel property

Comment: You misunderstand what viewDidLoad is for.  Those values won't get to it when the app reads viewDidLoad.  Do it with viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Comment: I've edited and included the additional code from the data model and initial VC. I can pass over an array of objects to `passengers` it is only when I want to filter and append values to the new array in the DetailVC